# "Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name" - When saved as Workbook_Deactivate

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to save each sheet in my workbook to cell A1 when i exit and also clearing a load of cells when I exit. Why am i getting the error in the title. This is my code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate(cancel As Boolean)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Clear prior disaggregated returns data
    With Worksheets("Scenario Results")
        'Down scenario reuslts
        .Range("J8:J" & .Range("J8").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
        .Range("K8:K" & .Range("K8").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
        .Range("L8:L" & .Range("L8").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
        .Range("M8:M" & .Range("M8").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
        .Range("N8:N" & .Range("N8").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
        .Range("O8:O" & .Range("O8").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
        .Range("P8:P" & .Range("P8").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
        'Base scenario results
        .Range("R8:R" & .Range("R8").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
        .Range("S8:S" & .Range("S8").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
        .Range("T8:T" & .Range("T8").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
        .Range("U8:U" & .Range("U8").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
        .Range("V8:V" & .Range("V8").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
        .Range("W8:W" & .Range("W8").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
        .Range("X8:X" & .Range("X8").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
        'Up scenario reuslts
        .Range("Z8:Z" & .Range("Z8").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
        .Range("AA8:AA" & .Range("AA8").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
        .Range("AB8:AB" & .Range("AB8").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
        .Range("AC8:AC" & .Range("AC8").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
        .Range("AD8:AD" & .Range("AD8").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
        .Range("AE8:AE" & .Range("AE8").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
        .Range("AE8:AF" & .Range("AF8").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
    End With

'Save in cell A1 everytime
    Dim sht As Worksheet, csheet As Worksheet
    Set csheet = ActiveSheet
        For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            If sht.Visible Then
            sht.Activate
            Range("A1").Select
            ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
            ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
            End If
    Next sht

csheet.Activate

applictaion.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: The `Workbook_Deactivate` event has no arguments. You cannot make up your own I'm afraid.

Comment: You have, btw, a typo (from Cut&Paste?) in the last `ClearContent`-row ('AE' instead of 'AF'). That's the punishment for not using a loop...

Comment: Thanks @FunThomas - how would I loop such a thing? My active cell range is huge as well and my file size is big, is there a way to stop that happening by tweaking the above?

Answer (score 0):

Jack,

Here's how to do the loop:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ClearRangeLoop()

   Dim Col As Integer
   Dim Ltr As String

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")

        For Col = 10 To 16  'J through P
           Ltr = Chr(64 + Col)
          .Range(Ltr & "8:" & Ltr & .Range(Ltr & "8").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
        Next Col

    End With

End Sub 'ClearRangeLoop
```

You'll have to do a little more work when you get to the double letter columns.

HTH